# You have held broken packages - Postgres gem for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu

So when ever I attempt to do bundle install I am told to make sure the pg gem is installed successfully, so when I do the `gem install pg vx.xx` I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/adam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

So then I do:

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

But I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.1.14-0ubuntu0.12.04) but 9.3.5-1.pgdg12.4+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I have 9.1 of everything else installed from postgres and pgadmin, and I have any 9.3 repos disabled. I have done a `sudo apt-get update` but I think the error is pretty obvious. So How do I make it not try and install 9.3.5 .... and go with 9.1.14?

Comment: What's your /etc/apt/sources.list ? Plus any /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ entry for postgresql or pgdg. Please also show the output of `apt-cache policy libpq5` and `apt-cache policy libpq-dev`

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this very problem. I found the solution here: http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/03/how-to-install-specific-version-of.html

Essentially:

```
$: apt-get install libpq5=9.1.14-0ubuntu0.12.04
$: apt-get install libpq-dev=9.1.14-0ubuntu0.12.04
$: apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1
```

Comment: That might work, but it's just kicking the problem down the road with another workaround. They need to figure out why they've got a `libpq5` from PGDG, but `libpq-dev` is coming from ubuntu's core repos.

Comment: My own experience was on AWS. The machine was Ubuntu 12.04, and I needed to install PostGIS 2.1 on PostgreSQL 9.1 - which wasn't available without adding a new source repo for apt-get to check. I'd guess this is probably what happened here too?

Comment: Yes, if PGDG packages were installed by hand rather than using apt, or the PGDG repo was enabled, used, then later removed. The point is that they shouldn't have packages that aren't associated with a repo, really, so they need to figure out what happened and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, after trying multiple solutions my problem

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

````
but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg)  
but it is not installable
           Depends: ```libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg)  
but it is not installable
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
````

The above resolved by uninstalling Postgresql and pgAdmin and downloading it from the official website

https://www.postgresql.org/

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/