# Docker, install postgresql in a container contain "ubuntu:14.04", lost when out of the container

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, docker, containers

I tried to install postgresql-9.3 in the container contains images "ubuntu: 14:04"

The first step, which I did make images "ubuntu: 14:04"

```
 $ sudo Docker pull ubuntu:14.04
```

The second step, I create a container with the command

```
 $ sudo docker run -t -i ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

The third step, I install postgresql-9.3 in a container contain "ubuntu:14.04" (in a container containing ubuntu)

I tried to get in postgresql could, then I tried to get out containers,  straight out with the command

```
 # exit
```

I tried to log back in, the container postgresql I install missing,
whether it can do and helped explain why?

Docker itself, whether running in the kernel?

Hardware> OS> Docker.

Docker concept:

Docker = images> Container

Answer (score 2):

You should not install anything in a bash session.
Since docker uses [UnionFS (union filesystem service)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS), as soon as you exit your bash session, any modification is lost when the container is removed.

You could try a `docker commit` of your "Exited" container, but that is not how you build a new image.

What you do is create a text file named `Dockerfile`, in which you follow similar steps as the [official postgres image `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/ed23320582f4ec5b0e5e35c99d98966dacbc6ed8/9.4/Dockerfile) (except you want to start from ubuntu).

It includes:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-common \
    && sed -ri 's/#(create_main_cluster) .*$/\1 = false/' /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf \
    && apt-get install -y \
        postgresql-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \
        postgresql-contrib-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

You the run `docker build -t mypostgres .`: that will build a new image which will contain postgres.

In other words, the Dockerfile is there to persists the installation steps in a declarative text file, from which you can build an image at any time.

Comment: gagal pada saat akan build dockerfile $ sudo docker build -f /path/docker_postgres .

Comment: gagal? Apa pesan kesalahan yang Anda miliki? 
Perintah Anda harus `docker build -t name -f /path/to/your/dockerfile`, bukan `-f /path/docker_postgres .`: Final dot karena Dockerfile dalam folder saat. Jika tidak, Anda tidak harus memiliki titik akhir.

Comment: Ada kesalahan saat akan build 
"E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Itu adalah postgres masalah specifc: lihat http://stackoverflow.com/q/25393203/6309

Answer (score 1):

If you find easier to install all with bash and not with Dockerfile and build command you could do exactly as you wrote for first and second steps but after as third step quit bash with

`CONTROL + P` followed by `CONTROL + Q`

that's will exit container leaving it running and after use

```
docker commit mycurrentcontainer mynewimagewithpostgrestobeuseinfuture
```

Answer (score -1):

This has fixed the issue. These steps are followed

Step1:
     Docker builds -t Mohan.
step2:
     Docker run -it Mohan bash
     Mohan is your container name

This is my Dockerfile:

FROM Ubuntu: 18.04

FROM postgres: 9.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
RUN echo postgres:postgres | chpasswd

RUN pg_createcluster 9.6 main --start

CMD /etc/init.d/postgresql start

CMD su -c "psql -c \"ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';\"" postgres

Comment: Hi, this is my script file.    
apt-get update && apt-get install -q -y postgresql-9.6 postgresql-client-9.6 postgresql-contrib-9.6 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
echo postgres:postgres | chpasswd
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
su -c "psql -c \"ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';\"" postgres