# How to build dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have made images ubuntu 14:04 on dockerfile

I am running the syntax

```
  $ sudo docker build -t mypostgres .
```

but I am still confused as to build the dockerfile
how to build it?

Comment: Silahkan kembali pertanyaan terakhir Anda , menerima jawaban yang ditutup -pertanyaan ( seperti di http://stackoverflow.com/a/33914235/6309 )

Comment: Here is an article giving [the best practice for writing a Dockerfile](https://hub.qovery.com/guides/engineering/best-practices-and-tips-for-writing-a-dockerfile/) and [this one on how to write a Dockerfile](https://hub.qovery.com/guides/tutorial/how-to-write-a-dockerfile/).

Answer (score 10):

`sudo docker build -t mypostgres .` means:

- process the file named '`Dockerfile`' (default name)
- located in the current folder (that is the final `.`)
- and build as a result the image named `mypostgres`

So if you have a [Dockerfile starting with `FROM postgres`](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/postgres#how-to-extend-this-image), you can execute your command and have your own postgres image in no time.

Answer (score 1):

Dockerfile is not as complex as it looks. here's a good start article that could help you to build your first docker file easily - http://rominirani.com/2015/08/02/docker-tutorial-series-writing-a-dockerfile/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read the [doc of Dockerfile best practice by Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/), better than any article IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a docker file direct from git repository or from a director.

to build a docker file first create a docker file inside your project and name it just **Docker** without any extension. Now inside that file write necessary command for building an image. For example

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

[image]

->Build from git:
**sudo docker build https://github.com/lordash/mswpw.git#fecomments:comments**

in here:
**fecomments** is branch name and **comments** is the folder name.

->building from git with tag and version:
**sudo docker build https://github.com/lordash/mswpw.git#fecomments:comments -t lordash/comments:v1.0**

->Now if you want to build from a directory: first go to comments directory the run command **sudo docker build .**

->if you want to add tag you can use **-t or -tag** flag to do that:
**sudo docker build -t lordash .** or **sudo docker build -t lordash/comments .**

-> Now you can version your image with the help of tag:
**sudo docker build -t lordash/comments:v1.0 .**

->you can also apply multiple tag to an image:
**sudo docker build -t lordash/comments:latest -t lordash/comments:v1.0 .**